# Why doesn't package_data get installed from sdist tarball?

Tags: python, setuptools

Here's the setup.py for a small package I've written:

```
$ cat setup.py 
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="tracks",
    version="0.1",
    description="WSGI-Applikationen Tracks",
    packages=["tracks"],
    package_data={'': ["templates/*"]},
    install_requires=['flask', 'sqlalchemy', 'pandas', 'matplotlib',
        'geographiclib', 'colorbrewer', 'mysql'],
    zip_safe=False
)
```

When I run "setup.py install" from the source dir, everything gets installed in my venv, including the templates directory. When I do setup.py sdist --formats=gztar, the templates/ directory with its contents is copied into the tarball (I see it in "tar tvzf ..."), but when I install that tarball using pip, the templates directory doesn't get installed.

I've tried to follow [this section](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files) of the setuptools instructions. What am I doing wrong? My understanding of pip is that it unpacks the tarball and then runs the setup.py script it finds there. When I do that "by hand", everything gets installed, so the tarball is fine.

Comment: Could you show a summed up version of your directory tree? In particular: where are your top level packages, and your templates relatively to your setup script?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the data files to be correctly packaged `package_data` has to be part of a *package*. It looks like *package data* is not contained in any of your *packages*, this can not work. In your case, make sure that your `templates` directory is in your `tracks` top level package.

Answer (score 0):

Upon re-reading the documentation, I found that in setup()'s arguments, both package_data=[...] and install_package_data=True must be set.